# Runtime Error: RuntimeError: No SFNT name table / Python 3.4 matplotlib 1.4.3

Tags: python, matplotlib

after installing matplotlib 1.4.3 i got RuntimeError: No SFNT name table. Does anyone struggled into the same issue and can help me out?

The following exceptions were raised:

[image: Exception]

Comment: the interesting exception is the top one, which says that `C:\\Users\lbui\.matplotlib\fontList.py3k.cache'` doesn't exist. Can't help more than that (I don't use matplotlib much), but clearly either some matplotlib setup didn't happen, or it's not installed correctly. You might try (since it looks like you're using pycharm) opening a regular console and doing `import matplotlib`, which might convince it to do its normal setup, or reinstalling it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Anaconda as my primary python system and the problem were gone. Maybe it has something to do with the ms compiler toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Removing fonts that you installed manually.